# How to make a horizontal pagination?

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, cascade

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the Momentics IDE 2.1.2 (native SDK).

I'm looking for a sample that shows how to build a horizontal pagination like in the image below that I will put it inside a container replacing with that a listview with a grid display.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html

Comment: there is no "StackView " in BB cascades.

Comment: then probably [NavigationPane](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__navigationpane.html)

Comment: `NavigationPage` or a `ListView` with horizontal orientation. There is at least the [StocQt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-demos-stocqt-example.html) example built around that latter approach.

Comment: true, but may be my question is not clear. Actually, all I want is to built a horizontal pagination between items replacing a simple listview display and navigationPane is working only with pages not inside containers

Comment: What's wrong with the ListView that you want to replace ?

Comment: The client wants that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy build simple pagination using `ListView` only. Hope the example below will be usefull:

```js
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    width: 600
    height: 800

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        model: 5
        clip: true
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: listView.width
            height: listView.height
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "page " + index
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: 30
        Row {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            Repeater {
                model: listView.model
                Rectangle {
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    border.width:2
                    border.color: "white"
                    color: index == listView.currentIndex ? "orange" : "white"
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that even using BB 10.3.1, you can find only QtQuick 1.0 & QtQuick 1.1 and I can not access to window or layout because they don't exist.

Comment: Ah, really? Why that heppends? There is no way to use QtQuick 2?

Comment: I didn't fnd anything that makes that possible.

Comment: It may be possible with `Flickable` and `Row`. Are these items exist in QtQuick1?

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it work with QtQuick1. I cannot test it but `ListView` exists in QtQuick1 and I guess it should work.